# How to get contacts from phonebook and sim but skype, facebook etc. in android

Tags: android

I'm trying do retrieve a list of contacts in phonebook and SIM, excluding contacts from skype, google, facebook and so on. I use the following code, but it works only on Samsung devices, I think because "vnd.sec.contact.phone" and "vnd.sec.contact.sim" used as selection arguments for ACCOUNT_TYPE field are both vendor related. How rewrite this code in a more "generic" way?

```
private Cursor getContactsNew()
{
    // Run query
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
            ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE
    };
    String selection = ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "= ? OR " + ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "= ?";
    String selectionArgs = new String[] { "vnd.sec.contact.phone", "vnd.sec.contact.sim" };
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    return cr.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial should help you out to fetch contacts from an android device :

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e5156/fetch-contacts-from-android-phone-in-android-studio/

Lemme know if it helped out

Comment: Sorry @Zakdroid, maybe my question was inaccurate or incomplete. I'm trying to implement an app that displays/prints various contact information like phone numbers, email addresses, organization, etc. To do that I need to distinguish those who are phonebook and SIM contacts, from contacts of various services such as Skype, WatsApp, Facebook and so on.